# PIP UPGRADE - Trouble with versions in personal setup package

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools

I'm working on my first python package, so I'm new with all this.

I have my own setup package which I install through `pip install git+<URL>.git`.

When I try to upgrade it with the `--upgrade` flag, it always get reinstalled, even if I haven't changed the version in my `setup.py` file.

Does anyone know why this is happening? o maybe have a better approach to this?

I have made my research before asking, but I think this is a very specific problem.

I have tried in a `venv` and out.

python 3.7, pip 19.2, setuptools 40.8

```py
# setup.py

from test import __version__
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="test",
    version=__version__,
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

I expect to get something similar to:

`Requirement already up-to-date: test in ./<cwd>/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.1)`

but instead I get this:

```
Installing collected packages: test
  Found existing installation: test 0.0.1
    Uninstalling test-0.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled test-0.0.1
  Running setup.py install for test ... done
Successfully installed test-0.0.1
```

Comment: Try forcing upgrade strategy adding `--upgrade-strategy only-if-needed` flag to install command. Help says it should be this way by default, but it seems it does exactly the opposite

Comment: Thanks, @papercut, I did it, bot got the same:

`pip install --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed git+<URL>
Requirement already satisfied: Click==7.0 in ./.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from test==0.0.1) (7.0)
Installing collected packages: test
  Found existing installation: test 0.0.1
    Uninstalling test-0.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled test-0.0.1
  Running setup.py install for test ... done
Successfully installed test-0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support) it seems like the expected behaviour to me.

> Note that if a satisfactory version of the package is already installed, the VCS source will not overwrite it without an --upgrade flag.

Read a somewhat related discussion here:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2837

Looks like `pip` does upgrades in a much more binary fashion when *VCS* is involved. It seems to always upgrade when `--upgrade` is set and never when it's not set.

You could try the work-around that is suggested in this discussion, but be aware of its side effects (for example, you will have a full clone of the git repository on your file system):

```
pip install --editable --upgrade git://somewhere/something.git
```

Comment: Thanks, @sinoroc, but the thing is if I use `pip install --upgrade`, the package gets uninstalled and installed again, even if it the version hasn't change. But if I do it with another package (i.e. pip), i get the `Requirement already up-to-date` message

Comment: Yes. As the documentations says that's how pip works when installing directly from a VCS. You could try the suggested work-around with its side effects: `--editable`. Next step would be to file a feature request for `pip`.

Comment: I read your question and comment again and I realized your issue is indeed slightly different than what is mentioned in the doc and the GitHub discussion. Looks like `pip` does upgrades in a much more binary fashion when _VCS_ is involved. It seems to always upgrade when `--upgrade` is set and never when it's not. I would give `--editable` a try. Have you tried specifying a _git commit hash_?

Comment: I have tried using `--editable` when I am in fact editing my code, but I think the installation should stay in the standard behavior of packages. I wouldn't like to use this workaround for the distribution

Comment: _I wouldn't like to use this workaround for the distribution_. Agreed. _I think the installation should stay in the standard behavior of packages_. This issue could be raised on the `pip` bug tracker. But I assume it is a technical choice that has been made, a compromise that had to be taken by the `pip` developers to allow installing from VCS repositories, as a commodity during development phase, not as a durable solution for the distribution of packages.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the solution, but was hoping to get a solution or reach someone who figured it out. Well... Thanks for the try, @sinoroc!